# What is the purpose of anchor transaction file in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In BYFN documentation after the channel.tx file, it generates `ORG1MSPanchors.tx`

> Next, we will define the anchor peer for Org1 on the channel that we
>   are constructing.

```
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
```

I understood the purpose of creating the transaction file, but where it is utilizing?

`genesis.block` - used for creating the channel
`channel.tx` - use for creating the channel
`ORG1MSPanchors.tx` -- Where does it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the anchor peer [concept](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/glossary.html#anchor-peer):

> A peer node on a channel that all other peers can discover and
>   communicate with. Each Member on a channel has an anchor peer (or
>   multiple anchor peers to prevent single point of failure), allowing
>   for peers belonging to different Members to discover all existing
>   peers on a channel.

When you create a channel using the channel.tx, there is not anchor peer defined for default. For this reason, you need to set it. At the first time you update anchor peer transaction will set the address and MSP of your anchor peer.
So continuing the BYFN tutorial, you need to tell the network that you have set a new anchor peer creating a config channel update transaction:

```
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

Comment: Where we do this above step in node-SDK? Where do we update the channel by anchor tx in node-SDK? Take the ref of the balance transfer, we only use mychannel.tx while creating a channel. In all the operations of the balance transfer, it didn't use anchor tx.

Comment: Yes, it does, [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/app/update-anchor-peers.js) you have the sample. Anyways, with `client.updateChannel()` you can update your [channel config](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Client.html#updateChannel).

Comment: Thank you for the ref. I was reading readme whole time and they didn't mention it there.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor peer update only works for the first update after channel creation. Please read this - https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/68669467#7419

If anyone has discovered a different way to add anchor updates after the first update, it would be very helpful to know. I am in the situation wherein I need to add orgs to a channel after the channel is created, and I am unable to add any anchor peers to the org because of this restiction.

Comment: I am stuck at updating anchor peer too

Answer (score 0):

The channel configuration is the main component of any fabric network. If any changes made in the network like a new organization in the network or making existing peer as an anchor peer, the channel is unaware of these changes. So, to make these changes as part of the channel we have to update the channel configuration.

In case of making a peer as an anchor peer, we have to create a new `anchorpeer.tx` file using  `configtxgen tool` and `-outputAnchorPeersUpdate` flag.

Now, with this generated tx file channel configuration needs to be updated. This will inform the channel that a particular peer is now an anchor peer.

To check how to update this, please follow the [Alexander Yammine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689912/9790416) answer to this question.